# How to hide link in status bar

Tags: php, html

I cannot understand how can hide link in status bar to guest, my php codes below:

```
//file column
    echo '<td width="75%" class="default_td" align="left" valign="top"><a class="default_a" href="', $this_file;
    $npart = $dir . $value;
    if (preg_match('/\|$/', $value)) //it is a link, not an actual file
    {
        $value = substr($value, 0, -1);
        $npart = substr($npart, 0, -1);
        $display = get_stored_info($value, $dir.$links_file);
        if ($display == '')
        {
            $display = $value;
        }
        echo 'dir=', translate_uri($subdir), '&amp;link=',
            translate_uri($value), '" title="Click here to Download ', $filename, '">',
            icon(ext($display)), htmlentities($display), '</a>';
    }
```

and i have found a method, the method working html fine. but how can i apply the method my above php code or how it worked?  the method below:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer"  onclick="javascript: window.location = 'http://www.mydomain.com/';">Go To SO</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply echo the string in your PHP but remember to escape the quotes?

```
<?php
    echo '<a style="cursor: pointer"  onclick="javascript: window.location = \'http://www.mydomain.com/\';">Go To SO</a>';
    // Remember to escape 's as they're also used to create the string       ^^                        ^^
?>
```

**Also;** Please do not post a link to your questions as comments on other questions. Instead, try to tag your post with valid tags so people will see your question on their frontpage. For your post I'd suggest [php](/questions/tagged/php) [html](/questions/tagged/html) and perhaps even [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Why would you want to hide the link any way? If you have hidden data, consider hidden fields, `$_SESSION` variables, `$_POST` variables, cookies, etc.

Comment: see those links: http://www.silkroadbd.net/site-demo/ http://www.silkroadbd.net/site-demo/ link hide with javavoid, but link not work when i click

Comment: @sanjidasona Don't be mean to everyone else searching about how to fix this problem. Update your original post and explain what you did to fix it so others googling the same problem will figure out what they're done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<a href="http://pustakakoran.com" onMouseOver="window.status='Go to MyWebsite'; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" >PustakaKoran</a>
```

Comment: "The status property does not work in the default configuration of IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera 15 and newer." : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp